# Disable UAC and XP Pro 32 Bit

Tags: windows-xp, security, permissions, uac

It seems the latest patches have included some kind of UAC in XP - I can't seem to find a way to disable it.  Does anyone know how/where?

The reason I ask (I may be wrong on UAC) - but when I log in to my PC as a non local Admin and try and install software it refuses and says you have to be "Administrator to install software".  So I right click on the exe and it says "Run As" - which is kind of indicates some kind of UAC is at play here.

Comment: UAC in XP?? Never heard of it... a screenshot would be nice.

Comment: Agreed with @heavyd -- I've heard nothing of this sort. Could you provide a screenshot, or clarify your description? Are you sure you aren't seeing something caused by some sort of malware?

Comment: There is no UAC in XP. What you are seeing is the normal prompt when a limited user tries to install software on XP. It has been this way since day 1 and was not introduced in a patch.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Non-administrator users on Windows XP aren't allowed to install new software. Change the account settings to administrator to get rid of this. It isn't *actually* UAC but just a notification to tell you you just can't install software with the current account.

Comment: Do I do this on the local PC or via Active Directory on the domain account settings?

Comment: @Vidar - Depends on where accounts are managed, if managed through a local domain, contact your system administrator. Of it just your own PC, just edit the account's settings through an administrator account. And thanks for getting me to 5000+ rep :D